# Typescript - How to find an array with attribute and then add an array inside this array

Tags: typescript

I've the following interface with a const who inherits it:

```js
interface TreeNode {
    name: string;
    children?: TreeNode[];
}

const TREE_DATA: TreeNode[] = [
    {
        name: 'Mes services',
    }, {
        name: 'Logiciels externes',
        children: [
            { name: 'Facturation' },
            { name: 'Add-on' },
        ]
    }, {
        name: "Collecteurs d'espace client",
        children: [
            { name: 'Banques' },
            { name: 'Fournisseurs' },
        ]
    }, {
        name: 'Services partenaires',
        children: [
            { name: 'Avocats' },
        ]
    }
];
```

I would like to find the array with the `Collecteurs d'espace client` name attribute and then add a new `TreeNode` in its `children` array.

Answer (score 0):

To find the entry with that `name`:

```js
const myNode = TREE_DATA.find(item => item.name === "Collecteurs d'espace client")
```

Manipulate it as you wish:

```js
myNode.children = whatever

// or

myNode.children.push(whatever)
```

Comment: If this answer helped you / was the answer, please mark it as such so that this question does not go without an answer.  Upvotes are nice too